# Cacti, problem with timezone

Tags: cacti

I'm installing Cacti on LXC container.
Works all, except for timezone configuration

on php.ini I have

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Rome"
```

on /etc/profile I have

```
TZ='Europe/Rome'; export TZ
```

on mariadb I have

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone';
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| time_zone     | Europe/Rome |
+---------------+-------------+
```

On cacti page...

[image]

what I miss?
I have also reboot the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
After restart container all works fine.